# GCC ARM NONE > 4.8.* cross compiler missing C99 math functions if compiled with cxx11 standard

Tags: gcc, arm, std

I noticed that most of the standard library math functions are not accessible if I compile with cross ARM GCC version 4.9.* in cxx11 mode. 
I tried to compile Eigen, as it has ARM optimizations but this just works with native compilers. 
The reason is that these standard library functions are within guard flags, which could have been overrided like this till version 4.8.*

```
#pragma once
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #define RAND_MAX __RAND_MAX
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
    #define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_FP_MACROS_DYNAMIC 1

    #include <AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/Core>
    #include <AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/Dense>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Since 4.9.* I get again complains, as there are even more utterly useless checks within the standard library. E.g. std::lgamma can not be found, or std::max is not existing ..
Does someone know a good way to bypass these guard flags in 4.9.*? Additionally, I wonder why cross GCC for ARM is doing this? There is no reason for this, as the code works 100% on these platform and it gets worse and worse with every compiler version ..

Comment: The [Linaro 15.05 build of 4.9.3](http://releases.linaro.org/15.05/components/toolchain/binaries/) compiles [this example code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/lgamma) without complaint under `-std=c++11`. What build of GCC are you using?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

Comment: Ah, right. Frankly I'm not overly surprised a bare-metal toolchain build targeting microcontrollers might have given up trying to offer a complete C++ library, especially given how the C++ standards committee shovel yet more of Boost into the language every few years. Building just that trivial lgamma example code statically gives a 907KB ELF that strips down to a 641KB binary, even trying to keep it small with `-Os -Wl,-gc-sections`. There's not too many Cortex-M devices that would even fit on...

Comment: The problem is that I try to port Eigen to ArduPilot. I don't care so much about size, but would like to get Copters profit from a higher level linear algebra library.

Comment: Well, looking at [the hardware list](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/supported-autopilot-controller-boards/) you _could_ presumably cater for the BeagleBone-based ones using a Cortex-A `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` toolchain.